# In Ruby 2.0 how do you use the mix method for traits

Tags: ruby

```
module A

end

class D

  mix A

end  

c1 = D.new
```

Here is my output:

```
archie@local$ruby mixins-traits.rb 
mixins-traits.rb:4:in `<class:D>': undefined method `mix' for D:Class (NoMethodError)
    from mixins-traits.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits didn't make it into Ruby 2.0. They are neither mentioned in the [Release Notes](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/) nor in the [NEWS](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/NEWS).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby has mix keyword? usually it use include keyword. example:
   `class D include A end`.

Comment: I think it was more for a conceptual display that the OP chose the word mix. He's effectively wondering how to do a mixin. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to add an include, for example:

```
module A
  def a1
  end
end

class Sample  
  include A    #include method
end

samp = Sample.new
```

Comment: Please learn how to [format your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).