# On what basis ruby and ruby on rails versions are named

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am curious on what basis ruby and ror versions are named. For example, after ruby 1.9.3, its version is 2.0 instead of 1.10 or 1.9.4, and so in rails. There must be some convention or rule.

Comment: As for Ruby, the versioning policy changed a few times over the time. Confer discussions [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7252).

Answer (score 5):

Ruby and Rails, like many other projects follow [Semantic Versioning](http://SemVer.Org/).

They don't always follow it to the letter, though. For example, Ruby 1.9 is backwards-incompatible with Ruby 1.8, whereas Ruby 2.0 is mostly compatible with Ruby 1.9, so really Ruby 1.9 should have been Ruby 2.0 and Ruby 2.0 should have been Ruby 2.1.

In this particular case, there were historic "marketing" reasons for that: the term "Ruby 2.0" has been used in the Ruby community for over 10 years now to mark a specific "mythical" version with specific, often talked-about features like scoped monkey patching and traits. Releasing a version *without* those features but still calling it "2.0" would have been *more* confusing than breaking the rules of Semantic Versioning. (Actually, Ruby 2.0 *was* released without traits and [it *has* led to confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15871618/2988)!)

OTOH, it was impossible to call it "1.10", because the `RUBY_VERSION` constant returns the version as a `String`, and a lot of tools (incorrectly) do something like

```
if RUBY_VERSION <= '1.8'
  def foo
  end
end
```

which would break, because the `String` `'1.10'` is actually *less than* the `String` `'1.8'`.

Therefore, it was decided to settle on 1.9.

Comment: I agree with Rails, but Ruby does not follow semver at all. After 1.8.6, 1.8.7 introduced many new features; 1.9.0 and 1.9.1 were essentially beta releases; 1.9.2 was backwards incompatible with 1.9.0 and 1.9.1; 2.0 is mostly backwards compatible with 1.9.2 but not 1.9.1 and 1.9.0, etc. And in contrast with semver, when bugs are fixed instead of incrementing the third digit a new patch level version is released (e.g. 1.9.2-p392).

Answer (score 1):

I think Ruby and Rails follow more or less [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), roughly meaning if the version is X.Y.Z, you change Z when you just fix a bug. Change Y if you add something (therefore all program depending on it, can say I need at least version X.Y) and you change X if you introduce backward incompatibility). 
X, Y and Z are usually called, Major, Minor and revision .